# Magento2: Add Checkout Terms and Conditions to Customer Registration Page

Tags: magento2, customer, registration, terms-and-conditions, required

I am trying to include terms and conditions that are shown on the checkout on the customer registration form. I have tried various ways and managed to get it to display correctly but no matter what I try I cannot make it work as a required field and each attempt the customer can still register without agreeing to the T&C's.

Any help or suggestions on the best way to implement this would be really appreciated!

Comment: Did you manage to get it done?

Answer (score 3):

I have put a Terms and Conditions checkbox on the register form. It might be useful for you if you just want a checkbox.

You must put this in the phtml form you are editing:

```
<div style="width: auto; margin: 0;" class="field choice newsletter">
        <input type="checkbox" data-validate="{required:true}" name="custom-terms" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Terms & conditions') ?>" id="register-input-custom" class="checkbox">
        <label for="custom-terms" class="label">
            <span>
                <?php echo __('I have read and accept the ') ?><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('privacy_policy');?>"><?php echo __('PRIVACY POLICY') ?></a><?php echo __(' and ') ?><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('terms_conditions');?>"><?php echo __('CONDITIONS OF USE') ?></a>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
```